# SkyDrive never running on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8.1, onedrive

I have two computers, both running Windows 8.1, one of which is working flawlessly with SkyDrive, everything uploading and downloading correctly. On the other computer SkyDrive worked for a while, and then one day without an error message or any other notice just stopped running. It doesn't show up in Task Manager, and even when I try forcing it to run through the command prompt, it still doesn't show up.

It still shows up in Windows Explorer and it shows it's in a state of downloading a file. All of the files in Explorer are out of date. When I open up the Metro app, it shows that it's downloading one file, when there should be thousands at this point, and when I click the `downloading 1 file` words in the top right corner it says that the file is done downloading in the next page. But when I return to the main Metro app area it still shows it downloading.

Is there anything else I can do to try to get it working?

edit: although not a part of my problem, if anyone else is having issues they can check [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/skydrive/folder-file-sync-error-faq). One notable limitation which many users might not know about is:

The entire path, including the file name, must contain fewer than 255 characters. Shorten the name of your file or the name of subfolders in SkyDrive, or select a subfolder that's closer to the top-level folder. Then follow these steps to start syncing your SkyDrive folder on the computer again:

1. Click Start, enter SkyDrive in the search box, and then click Microsoft SkyDrive. (On a Mac, use Spotlight to search for the SkyDrive app.)
2. Follow the steps to select your SkyDrive settings again, including picking the location of your SkyDrive folder and choosing whether to turn on the Fetch files feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped for me was running the skydrive troubleshooter found [here.](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9835055) There were a few other steps to getting it working 100%, but the troubleshooter helped a ton. Running the SDP advanced troubleshooter also helped get it back up and running. I'm not sure if you have to have that given to you by a Microsoft employee or not. I got it by posting on the help forums there about my issue.